# Curl Requests in PHP - Using an API

Tags: php, javascript, api

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Cheddar API (http://cheddarapp.com/developer) in my PHP application.

Cheddar's API uses curl requests - which have been fine for me using in terminal but not in my index.php.

I'd like to create a button that when clicked, creates a task in a list call Colors. If a list does not exist, it'll create the list.

Have anybody used Cheddar's API or even included curl requests in PHP or even how to include them in Javascript which I'm guessing you use for things of this matter.

**Update**

Here's the Curl request for creating a task in Cheddar: https://cheddarapp.com/developer/tasks#create.

I'd like to make a button that onclick, it will create a task. Is it not as a simple as creating a function in Javascript and using onclick on an anchor?

Comment: Is your PHP config setup with libcurl? http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Comment: I'm new to PHP. I just have an index.php file with an array in it. No config, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using now days curl Php

```
$LOCAL_REST_URL = 'whateverurlofyourrestapi'

$json_part = { pass the data for post }
```

you will get your response in `$buffer` in json format iterate it use the response

As u said how to make a curl request i would like to give you a simple POST example

```
            $curl_handle=curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$LOCAL_REST_URL);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,20);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_part);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
            curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Where $json_partis the request body and $LOCAL_REST_URL is is your rest url

I am hoping this post will help you

Comment: first go through curl POST means Create PUT stand for UPdate DELETE means delete and GET means get the detail

Answer (score -1):

You could run your terminal program with shell_exec from php.

Or transcript the curl-code to curl-requests from php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: Could I make a function in Javascript with the curl request in there?

Comment: well, the curl is executed on server, javascript on the client. But you could of course request the server by url or ajax request. (who's downvoting and why?)